# Converting existing dataframe as per requirement

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe as given below:

```
ID   Year-mo  procedure_code   no_of_procedure 
1    Jan-2010   I06              100  
1    Feb-2010   I06              200
2    Mar-2010   I06              300
2    Apr-2010   I06              400
```

I need to convert above dataframe into format such that procedure_code column values becomes individual columns with number no_of_procedure as their column values.

Expected output format given below:

```
ID   Year-mo    I06   
1    Jan-2010   100   
2    Feb-2010   200
3    Mar-2010   300
4    Apr-2010   400
```

Comment: This site is not for posting requirements and getting the code for free. You may want to read [the rules of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: can you provide a bit more complex example with other procedure codes? this looks like a `pivot` but not completely…

Comment: Brother...All I need is individual columns for all procedure codes from column procedure_codes and all individual columns must contains values from no_of_procedure column, other proceudre codes are I07,I08,I09 etc

Comment: I would be more explicit if you can include one or two more I07, I08 in your example by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71829835/edit) the question

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a modified [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) where you would reset the ID, but the logic is not fully clear.

From my current understanding, I would use:

```
(df
 .assign(ID=df.groupby('procedure_code').cumcount().add(1))
 .pivot(index=['ID', 'Year-mo'],
        columns='procedure_code',
        values='no_of_procedure')
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
   ID   Year-mo  I06
0   1  Jan-2010  100
1   2  Feb-2010  200
2   3  Mar-2010  300
3   4  Apr-2010  400
```

Comment: I incorporated your logic and it did worked thanks a-lot brother

Comment: When I tried to add another level which DIAGNOSIS_CODE which is similar to procedure code as I need unique DIAGNOSIS_CODE as columns along with their sum but below code is giving 
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape please tell me where I'm going wrong    df1 = (df.assign(ID=HCP_Procedure_df.groupby(['PROCEDURE_CODE','DIAGNOSIS_CODE']).cumcount().add(1))
 .pivot(index=['NPI', 'YEAR_MO'],
        columns=('PROCEDURE_CODE','DIAGNOSIS_CODE'),
        values=['NO_OF_PROCEDURES','NO_OF_DIAGNOSIS'])
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)  please help

Comment: better provide a clean reproducible example by editing your question

Comment: All I'm asking if I add another column say diagnosis  code having unique value similar to procedure code for which you provided solution how shall we modify code your code in such case. I need individual columns for each diagnosis code as well their sum values just how we did for procedure code.  I tried code as given in my above comment but it's giving 
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: IIUC, that's quite a different question, maybe ask a separate one?

Comment: my question is a add on to existing one it can be discarded as duplicate one

Comment: I don't think so, it's a different logic. Plus you haven't accepted the answer here so it cannot be linked as duplicate.

Comment: Asked new question can you please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857471/creating-pivot-as-per-requirement-in-python