# Creating pivot as per requirement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have following dataframe as given below:

```
ID   Year-mo  save_code   no_of_procedure  threat_code no_of_threats
1    Jan-2010   I06              100              T01          200
1    Feb-2010   I06              200              T01          300
2    Mar-2010   I06              300              T01          400
2    Apr-2010   I06              400              T01          500
```

I need to convert above dataframe into format such that procedure_code and `threat_code` column values becomes individual columns with number `no_of_procedure` and `no_of_threats` as their column values.

Expected output format given below:

```
ID   Year-mo    I06   T01
1    Jan-2010   100   200
2    Feb-2010   200   300
3    Mar-2010   300   400
4    Apr-2010   400   500
```

Please help

I tried code:

```
df1 = (df.assign(ID=df.groupby(['save_code','threat_code']).cumcount().add(1))
 .pivot(index=['ID', 'Year_mo'],
        columns=('save_code','threat_code'),
        values=['no_of_procedure','no_of_threats'])
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

But it's giving error

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Answer (score 2):

### `from_records` with comprehension

```
cols = ['ID', 'Year-mo', 'save_code', 'no_of_procedure', 'threat_code', 'no_of_threats']
pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [{'ID': a, 'Year-mo':b, c: d, e: f}
     for a, b, c, d, e, f in zip(*map(df.get, cols))]
)

   ID   Year-mo  I06  T01
0   1  Jan-2010  100  200
1   1  Feb-2010  200  300
2   2  Mar-2010  300  400
3   2  Apr-2010  400  500
```

Comment: nice one @piRSquared!

Comment: @piRsquared you didn't add ID column when I tried to add ID in your code and ran it output is where after save_code  threat_code is appearing in question I provided only 1 save_code and 1 threat_code but I have around 15 save_code and I want them to come one after other as individual column similarly for threat_code how shall I modify your code please tell me I used code  as given cols = ['ID','YEAR_MO', save_code', 'no_of_procedure', 'threat_code', 'no_of_threats'] pd.DataFrame.from_records( [{'NPI':a,'YEAR_MO': b ,c: d, e: f} for a, b, c, d, e, f in zip(*map(HCP_Procedure_df.get, cols))])

Comment: Your `'ID'` column didn't make sense.  It went from `[1, 1, 2, 2]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  Explain how you arrive at the result and I'll be happy to update the answer.

Comment: It's a typo actually ID is all 1 in dataframe given in question as it's for a single record only thank you

Comment: So wait... it should've been `[1, 1, 1, 1]` in the original dataframe and `[1, 1, 1, 1]` in the final as well?

Comment: Yes it has to only 1,1,1,1 as it's for single ID 1,data is at ID and Year-mo level for ex for Id 1 in jan 2010 I06 is 100, for Id 1 in feb 2010 I06 is 200 likewise for other months

Comment: I updated the answer assuming the same data you previously provided.  Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: Actually by your code output is coming like I06,T01,I07,T02,I08,T03 but I want it like I06,I07,I08,T01,T02,T03 i.e for different save_code I needed them to be one after other and similary for threat_code but it's coming like save_code then threat_code. I have 15 different save_code and threat_code so want 15 individual columns for save_code first then 15 individual columns of threat_code

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Can you provide a more comprehensive example in your question.  I'm sure its a simple matter but I'm not sure where to tweak the answer.

Comment: @piRquared  - Can you please check this question I'm also working on this requirement ty - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912708/creating-dataframe-in-python-based-on-user-requirement